# How to install scheme or mit-scheme on Ubuntu on UTM?

Tags: apt, scheme

I have a MacBook M2, so I am using UTM to run the virtual machine -- not emulation but virtualization mode.

I saw some YouTuber recommended installing the ARM version of Ubuntu server, and then install the desktop (the GUI) after that, because Ubuntu's website does not show an ARM Desktop to download.

However, that YouTuber also said I can use the ARM daily build of Desktop on:
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/

which is `jammy-desktop-arm64.iso`

However, after installation and even including auto update during the installation, I used Terminal and typed in:

```bash
$ scheme
scheme: command not found

$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for mike: 
Hit:1 http://us.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-proposed InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt install mit-scheme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mit-scheme is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mit-scheme-doc

E: Package 'mit-scheme' has no installation candidate
```

and all the online search results to how to install mit-scheme do not work.  I tried then on a 10 year old MacBook Air with an Intel chip, and install Ubuntu 22-04 Desktop, and typed in `scheme` and it automatically suggested that I run

```bash
sudo apt install mit-scheme
```

and was able to install it. So this installed version of Ubuntu knows about mit-scheme while the other one doesn't.

How can the first one be made to be able to know mit-scheme (and hopefully chezscheme also) and be able to install it?

Comment: The `mit-scheme` package is [only available for x64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mit-scheme), which means it will not appear on ARM-based installations. `chezscheme` *is* [available for the armhf platform](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/chezscheme-dev), but not arm64. You may need to try and compile from source to have these on your ARM-based installation.

Comment: so it is like I need the binary of mit-scheme for the ARM processor. So I guess one way can be to wait 2, 3 years until M1 and M2 Mac out number Intel Mac. However, if at that time there are 50% PC and 50% Mac, and there are 10% Intel Mac and 40% M1 and M2 Mac, then it is still 60% Intel and 40% M1 and M2. So to solve that issue, we may have to wait for somebody to port it to ARM or we can try it ourselves?

Comment: The Ubuntu packages site does include links to the source code, which *may* compile on ARM with a little bit of tweaking here and there, and there is also the name of the maintainer of the package(s). If working with source code isn't for you, perhaps a nice message to the maintainer will encourage them to work on the architecture port. There are no guarantees, though. A lot of these open source packages are open to encourage community contributions 

Comment: I see... so running Ubuntu on an M1 or M2 Mac may not be a great idea because you can run into problems when you need a program... easily if you try a web framework and it needs a certain program to run. So either get an older MacBook or Mac Mini with Intel chip, or just get a PC instead

Comment: Depending on what you want to use Ubuntu for, having an Intel/AMD-based machine may be the way to go. Only you can be the judge of this, though 

Comment: I just looked into getting a Microsoft Surface, and so the option of getting one with the Microsoft SQ 3 processor may not be a good idea if you are to run Ubuntu on it... the Intel ones will give you least headache, it seems